# Multiple tables in sqlite database

Tags: iphone

I have 3 tables in my database. How to combine those three tables in an array and how to retreive each data from a table?

Answer (score 0):

Use sql query with `JOIN`. Hope your tables are defined with proper relationships.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But first i have to take those tables in an array.

Comment: First you should get a resultset from tables, queries with join. then the resultset will be added to array using loop. sample query like "Select table1.column1, table1.colum2, table2.colum1 from table1 join table2 on table1.fk_column = table2.id". get on some good SQL JOIN example

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN sql query or u add common column name to all tables. then fetch data using the common column name.